# Let $S=\left\{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n; n=1,2,\dots \right\}$. We claim that $\inf(S)=2$ and $\sup(S)=e$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S=\left\{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n; n=1,2,\dots \right\}$. We claim that $\inf(S)=2$ and $\sup(S)=e$. Note that $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is an increasing function. Hence $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n=e.$

**Proof that $\inf(S)=2$:** We need to show that

1. $2$ is an lower bound for $S$;
2. if $b$ is any lower bound for $S$, then $2 \geq b$

For (1), we just observe that $2 \leq \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$, since it is the smallest value in the set $S$. To verify (2), we begin by assuming we are in possession of some other lower bound $b$. Because $2 \in S$ and $b$ is an lower bound for $S$, we must have $2 \geq b$, which is precisely what we need to show.

**Proof that $\sup(S)=e$:** We need to show that

1. $e$ is an upper bound for $S$;
2. if $b$ is any upper bound for $S$, then $e \leq b$

For (1), we just observe that $e \geq \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$. To verify (2), we begin by assuming we are in possession of some other upper bound $b$. Because $e\in S$ and $b$ is an upper bound for $S$, we must have $e\leq b$, which is precisely what we need to show.

I feel like this seems to generic. Is this a formal enough proof?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the second line. limit should be on n. $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \big(1 + {1 \over n} \big)^n$

Comment: Your statement that "$e \in S$" is false.

Comment: So how would I do it?

Comment: ^That depends on what your definition of $e$ is. Also, have you already shown that $(1+\tfrac{1}{n})^n$ is an increasing sequence?